# Ubuntu 16.04 Not Connecting to the Internet

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, internet, amd-graphics

I have built a PC recently, and have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 7 on it, but I'm having problems getting Ubuntu to connect to the internet. (Wireless)

The "available" networks show, but when I try to connect to one, it connect after a minute or so, and then after one or two seconds, it just disconnects again. On Windows 7, the internet works just fine.

I have set the IPv6 method to "ignore" and the password stored itself, (Those were the most common solutions I found online) and the problem persists.

What do I do?

If it helps, here are my specs:
8-core 4.0GHz AMD CPU
8GB RAM
AMD R9 Fury GPU
4TB Hybrid Drive (1.8TB used for Ubuntu Partition)

Using "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3" return this: http://prnt.sc/eipmav (Sorry for the camera-on-screen thing, my Ubuntu currently refuses to accept all but 2 of my PC's USB ports, both are taken up by my keyboard and mouse, so I had no way of getting copying and pasting the text.)

Comment: What do you call "internet"? How do you try to connect? Is it some wireless adapter, etc?

Comment: Oh right, it's a wireless network adapter I have installed in the PC.

Comment: Is it a PCI adapter?

Comment: Well, PCI-express, yeah,

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Done that, although I had no choice but to take a photo of the screen, seeing as Ubuntu on the PC currently refuses to accept all but 2 of the USB ports it has, both of which are taken up by the keyboard and mouse...

Comment: All is OK with drivers.

Comment: So why would it not be connecting to any networks?

Comment: What is the RF channel and encryption in your router?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't even know what an RF channel is, but the encryption is WPA/WPA2, if that's what you mean.

Comment: What do I do? I really need help...

Comment: First of all change use WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Those changes are made **at your router**.

Comment: Well, I don't want to tamper with the router, since I'm not the only one in the house using it, and even if there weren't, I don't know how to change the settings on a router...